# inspect --format '{{.State.OOMKilled}}' <container id> is true

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, lstm, docker-machine

I am running an LSTM network with a large data set. I have run my program for near one month on a host PC using docker on GPU without any problems.

Since 3 days ago I received kill message in my terminal and my container is always killed when I run my program. I checked this command: inspect --format '{{.State.OOMKilled}}'  and the answer was true. I wrote a very simple program and run this command the answer this time was false. However, even the simple program didn't have any results.
Can someone help me how to solve this problem?

Because it happens suddenly and I didn't change my program and anything else